# Getting Cell Values in JTable

Tags: java, swing

Anything wrong here?

```
    JButton btnCheckout = new JButton("Checkout");
    btnCheckout.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            racingUsr.setVisible(false);
            int row = 0;
            int col = 4; 
            int price = 0,subtotal = 0,qty = 0,rowin = table.getSelectedRow();

            if(rowin == 0){
            qty = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"How many of that game?"));
            Object a = table.getModel().getValueAt(row, col);
            a = price;
            subtotal = price * qty;

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, subtotal);
            }
        }               
    });
```

Table has 5 rows and 1 column (currently, cant add more yet with this error) coming in from the SQL database. When i enter '5' in the quantity, it outputs '0' in the subtotal. And i also need an extra help for the quantity count, when i buy a game, of course the quantity should decrease but how? I hope someone can help. TIA.

Error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1 >= 1
```

Comment: In which line the error occurs?

Comment: be sure that there is selected only one row by 1. if (table.getSelectedRow()) > -1 and 2. setting to the SelectionModel to SINGLE_Xxx_Xxx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 
a=price;
instead of 
price = a;

This is the reason because you get the 0 in the subtotal.

Comment: i'll look into it ^_^ just a second

Comment: `price =a;` says it cannot convert object to int. i added a cast, but it doesn't do anything.